# How can I make multiple words hyperlink to an internal cross-reference?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, ref

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  \label{th:01}
  Let \( a \) and \( b \) two real numbers. Then \( (a + b)^2 = a^2 +
  2ab + b^2. \).
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  \( (a + b)^2 = (a + b)(a + b) = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \).
\end{proof}
Theorem \ref{th:01} is a very important theorem!
\end{document}
```

In the output PDF the last line looks like:

> Theorem 1 is a very important theorem!

Only "1" of "Theorem 1" becomes a hyperlink to Theorem 1.

How can I write the LaTeX code such that the two words "Theorem 1" becomes a hyperlink to Theorem 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  \label{th:01}
  Let \( a \) and \( b \) two real numbers. Then \( (a + b)^2 = a^2 +
  2ab + b^2. \).
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  \( (a + b)^2 = (a + b)(a + b) = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \).
\end{proof}
\hyperref[th:01]{Theorem \ref*{th:01}} is a very important theorem!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or use `\hyperlink{th:01}{...}`